# Spring Caching with Couchbase - Views are not available on this bucket type

Tags: java, spring, caching, couchbase

I tried using couchbase-spring-cache to my application. Followed the configuration but upon my application started its throwing this error...

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]:
>   Factory method 'cacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is
>   com.couchbase.client.core.ServiceNotAvailableException: Views are not
>   available on this bucket type.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 47 more Caused by:
>   com.couchbase.client.core.ServiceNotAvailableException: Views are not
>   available on this bucket type.    at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.node.locate.ViewLocator.(ViewLocator.java:34)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.(RequestHandler.java:89)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.(RequestHandler.java:136)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseCore.(CouchbaseCore.java:178)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster.(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:262)

Is there anything I have to configure? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a "memcached" type bucket?

For now only buckets of type `Couchbase` are supported. Both the Spring Cache couchbase implementation and Spring Data Couchbase rely on `views` and `N1QL` to implement some features of the API, and these are not available on `memcached`-typed buckets.

In Cache, the view is necessary to collocate several caches in the same bucket and still be able to do a `clear`.

I'll update the README to clarify that. The alternative could be to use `flush` on a memcache bucket but this is very destructive is used wrong (you would have to make **100% certain** that **only the data of a single cache is stored in the memcache bucket**. Because clearing the cache would remove **ALL** documents contained in backing bucket. So for now it's not really on the roadmap.

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for your reply. Yes I am using a "memcached" type bucket. Thank you for clarifying that the implementation doesn't apply to memcached typed bucket. I might try to consider changing to couchbase type, or else I will just extend AbstractCacheManager to make it work with my current bucket type.

Comment: Simon, I tried changing my bucket to "couchbase" but now I'm getting the error com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: Could not open bucket. Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationException: Partition size is not equal after conversion, this is a bug. Can you me help on this?

Comment: looks like there is a discrepancy in the configuration obtained from the cluster, between the number of hosts in the `vBucketServerMap`/`partitionHosts` (resolved to IPs) and the list of `nodes`... Are you sure your cluster is in a healthy state and everything in in good shape at the network level / cluster configuration level?